# Is there any case in which repeated Bellman-Ford is better than Floyd-Warshall?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

Considering the fact that repeated Bellman-Ford has a time complexity of O(V(^2)*E) and Floyd-Warshall O(V^3), in which case is it better to use repeated Bellman-Ford to get the minimum paths of all pairs? In which case is it worse?

Comment: Kind of obviously if the graph is very sparse, i.e. O(E) < O(V).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know the complexity( repeated Bellman-ford = `O((V^2)*E)` and Floyd-warshall `O(V^3)`), you can easily analyze what would be better for you graph. If `E < V`  use Bellmam-ford, otherwise use Floys-warshall.

> Main application for Bellman ford is to find negative cycle in the graph. For Floyd warshall is to find all pair shortest path.

Normally in graph number of edges(E) are always greater than the vertices(V). So, i suggest to use **Floyd-warshall**.

If your graph has the possibility of having negative cycle, then you have to use Bellman ford to check whether the graph has negative cycle.

Comment: > If your graph has the possibility of having negative cycle, then you have to use Bellman ford to check whether the graph has negative cycle. 

Why can't Floyd Warshall be used to detect negative weight cycles?

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla implementation of Bellman Ford takes O(V*E) time for each run. It can only beat Floyd Warshall when E < V.

However, there is an optimization you can make. A variation of Bellman Ford that uses a queue, similar to how BFS works, except an element may be added to the queue multiple times when better cost is achieved. In practice, on randomly generated graphs, this tends to perform almost as well as Dijkstra with Heaps, which is O(E log V).

Comment: Is it really O(E log V)? I thought it would still be O(E*V)

Comment: Worst case is still O(E*V). However, unless the graph has a very particular structure, you won't have to update each node E times. So the size of your queue will be much smaller than E*V. That's because lots of those edges won't lead to a better cost. Usually the more dense the graph is, the better this algorithm will perform. Try implementing both versions and do a time comparison - you'll be amazed  :)